# Color bar depending on a parameter

Tags: color, legending, charts

I'm trying to reproduce a figure like the following:

[image: example]

I had the analytical expression for each curve, and the color bar indicates the value of some parameter. My problem is that I don't figure out how to program a bar like that.

For instance, let me assume that my parameter is A in

```
Plot[Table[A Sin[3 x], {A, 1, 10, 0.5}], {x, 0, 6}
```

How can I get a bar with the intensity of A?

I appreciate any comment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
Plot[Evaluate @ Table[A Sin[3 x], {A, 1, 10, 0.5}], {x, 0, 6}, 
 PlotStyle -> (ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"] /@ Rescale[Range[1, 10, .5]]), 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"BlueGreenYellow", {1, 10}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @kglr. Just another question: Do you know how to manange the Thickess and Dashing togheter with the instructions in your response?

Comment: Maybe you can do something like `PlotStyle -> (Directive[ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"]@#, 
     AbsoluteDashing[{5 - 3 #, 3 #}], AbsoluteThickness[4 - 2 #]] & /@
    Rescale[Range[1, 10, .5]])`?